# Wordpress: Theme original menu not hiding on mobile view

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress Responsive Menu-plugin. When in Mobile view I get two menus - the plugin menu and the theme's original menu.
I am working on local so I cant give you a web address.

Comment: can you tell that plugins name used

Comment: Plugin Name is WP Responsive Menu. Or suggest me other plugin. I am new to wordpress.

Comment: Its hard for us to answer your question without knowing what you did.

Comment: which plugin? because you have two menus? try for give more info in your questions please.

Answer (score 1):

find the wrapping div of the main menu and write a media query to hide it in mobile sizes.

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .wrapping-class{
        display: none;
    }
}
```